# kwonlyarg not correctly passed to decorator

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, keyword-argument

I got the following decorator:

```
from decorator import decorator

@decorator
def prepare_opts(decorated_func, *args, **kwargs):

args = list(args)
....
```

If I wrap the following function:

```
EMPTY_DICT = {}

@prepare_opts
def get_child_items_from_id(item_id, *single_opts,  additional_cond_q_def_dict=EMPTY_DICT,
                            **named_opts):
....
```

And call it like this:

```
child_items = ticket_functions.get_child_items_from_id(952549, additional_cond_q_def_dict={
                                                               'field': 'Summary',
                                                               'q_type': 'contains',
                                                               'value': 'ABC'
                                                           })
```

The decorator gets the tuple `(952549, {'field': 'Summary', 'q_type':'contains', 'value':'ABC'})` for `*args`

Actually I expect `additional_cond_q_def_dict` to be passed as entry of `**kwargs` and not as an entry in `*args`to the decorator. What did I miss here?

Comment: So what's the `decorator` decorator you are using?  The magic of assigning `args` and `kwargs` apparently happens in that decorator, but you don't tell us what it is.  It's not part of the Python standard library, so apparently you implemented it yourself or used some third-party library.  (I'd guess it's [this decorator](http://decorator.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests.documentation.html#decorator-decorator), but that's just a guess)

Comment: Yes sorry, it is the decorator package.